# Custom Content Element with IRRE via Typoscript -> empty array

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

i have a little problem getting a custom content element via typoscript on all pages.
i´ve created a custom element without any extensions (like mask or dce) so im only using
TYPO3 core functions. This Element is a simple thingy that just uses irre for creating
different boxes to be displayed in the frontend.

```
tt_content.box = COA
tt_content.box {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = EXT:xxx_elements/Resources/Private/Templates/Box.html
        partialRootPath = EXT:xxx_setup/Resources/Private/Content/Partials
        layoutRootPath = EXT:xxx_setup/Resources/Private/Content/Layouts
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                table = tx_xxxelements_box
                orderBy = sorting
                where {
                    data = field:uid
                    intval = 1
                    wrap = tt_content=|
                }
                as = boxitems
            }
        }
    }
}
```

rendered with normal fluid like

```
<f:for each="{boxitems}" as="boxitem">
  <boxitem.header>...
</f:for>
```

so everything works fine as long as i use it as a regular content element that is placed
on a page. now i put one element into a storagefolder and try to reuse this element on all pages via typoscript
where 10 is the ID of the content element

```
lib.SubFooter = COA
lib.SubFooter {
    10 = RECORDS
    10 {
        tables = tt_content
        source = 10
    }
}
```

the lib is rendered correct, but the "boxitems" array is empty on all pages :-(

now the funny part:
if i place the element with ID 10 on a page the boxitems array is filled for both element and lib...

Here is an image with the variable dump for different situations:
[element, lib, element+lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9QvN.png)

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? You can debug the SQL queries in frontend with the admin panel.

Comment: thats what the SQL looks like :-(
query => 'SELECT * 
    FROM tx_xxxcontentelements_box 
    WHERE tx_xxxcontentelements_box.pid IN(1) 
    AND tt_content=10 
    AND (tx_xxxcontentelements_box.sys_language_uid = 0) 
    AND tx_xxxcontentelements_box.deleted=0 
    AND tx_xxxcontentelements_box.t3ver_state<=0 
    AND tx_xxxcontentelements_box.pid<>-1 
    AND tx_xxxcontentelements_box.hidden=0 
    AND tx_xxxcontentelements_box.starttime<=1486999740 
    AND (tx_xxxcontentelements_box.endtime=0 OR tx_xxxcontentelements_box.endtime>1486999740) 
    ORDER BY sorting'

Comment: thats from the pid:1 when using the lib version nothing is displayed, at least nothing that could point me in the right direction :-(

Comment: ah! i found something, it seems like the query is always looking for records in the current PID... which is somehow confusing...

Comment: That is the normal behavior of TYPO3, unless you disable it in either TCA or in TS with `recursive = 99` https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help :) as im not a programmer myself i think its quite confusing that if i want to reuse an element via lib everything works and TYPO3 looks at the right PID/UID i defined with typoscript, but for the inline records of that parent element it looks on the current page instead the ones defined in typoscript?
i`ll try with CONTENT instead of RECORDS as you suggested, and let you know what happened :D

Comment: ok, tried both, didnt work properly. so i changed the Content Element to be just like a regular one (without irre) and then fetched them via typoscript. thanks a lot for your time @pgampe :)

Comment: Can you please report your solution as self-answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not find a satisfactory solution to the problem. In the end, I have built the content element as a normal element instead of IRRE, then the integration with typoscript works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're missing the pid ;-)

```
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        10 {
            ....
            pidInList.field = pid
```

and you can simplify in my opinion in this case the where clause:

```
            where.dataWrap = tt_content={field:uid}
```

because you're not matching against vars from outside...